# Saving user inputs - Python3.2

Tags: python, save, user-input

I am fairly new to python,

I am trying to make a program where the user types in a symbol and then a letter and then when they press enter it is replaced. I have managed to make it replace the symbol for a letter however once the user does it again, the previous letter they substituted doesnt save, it just goes back to the symbol that it was. I have tried looking for the answer myself but whatever i try comes up with an error, or doesn't seem to work. I was hoping that someone could help me.

Here is the part of my code for this:

```
s = 0
while s < 1000:
    clues_list=[]
    question1= input("What symbol:")
    question2= input("Which letter:")

    for symbol in words_list:
        newcontentsA = (word)
        newcontentsA = newcontentsA.replace('#','A') # the clues to help the user
        newcontentsA = newcontentsA.replace('*','M') # the clues to help the user
        newcontentsA = newcontentsA.replace('%','N') # the clues to help the user
        newcontentsA=newcontentsA.replace(question1,question2)
        print(newcontentsA)
        clues_list.append(newcontentsA)
```

Comment: Save user inputs in a dictionary.

Comment: You are using the never modified 'words_list' over and over again. Of course, all of its content remains unchanged. If you want to use the previously modified 'symbol's  you have to use 'clues_list' instead.